# how to stop event propagation on particular selected value in ng select?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I want to stop event and freeze the dropdown when I select a particular 'other' value in dropdown of ng-select.
The sropdown should not get closed when user selects 'Others - please specify your reason.'
and for all other values dropdown should get closed

```
      <div class="" *ngFor="let s of selectedSites">

              <div class="columnSite siteName">
                <span class="" [title]="s.site_nm">{{ s.site_nm }}</span>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="col-md-1"></div> -->
              <div class="columnSite">
                <div class="custom-ng-select add-sites__ng-selectReason">

                  <ng-select #ngSelectTa placeholder="Select" [items]="reasonForAddingArray" [multiple]="false"
                    [clearable]="false" [searchable]="false" (opened)="opened()" (click)="reasonForAdding(s,$event)">
                    <ng-template ng-multi-label-tmp let-item="item">
                      <div class="ng-placeholder custom-text">
                        {{ getPlaceholderLabel('ngSelectTa') }}
                      </div>
                    </ng-template>


                  </ng-select>
                  <input *ngIf='inputOtherReason' [id]="s.site_nm" type="text" class="form-control inputsearch"
                    #inputSearch placeholder="Enter Reason For Adding" (keyup)="reasonForAddingOther(s,$event)"
                    [ngClass]="errorCheck(s)" />
                </div>
              
                              </div>
            </div>
```

.ts

```
 reasonForAdding(site, $e) {
    console.log(site);
    console.log($e);
    let otherReason = $e.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(this.inputOtherReason);
    console.log(otherReason);
    if (Utils.isArrayExists(this.selectedSites)) {
      let reasonObj = { label: '', value: '' };
      if (otherReason != 'Others - please specify your reason.' && this.reasonForAddingArray?.includes(otherReason)) {
        reasonObj['label'] = otherReason;
        reasonObj['value'] = otherReason;
        this.inputOtherReason = false;
        this.openedValue = false;
        console.log(this.inputOtherReason);
      } else {
        this.inputOtherReason = true;
        console.log(this.inputOtherReason);
        reasonObj['label'] = 'Others';
        reasonObj['value'] = otherReason;
        this.openedValue = true;
        $e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       // $e.stopPropagation();
       // $e.preventDefault();
      }

    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling autoclose with `[closeOnSelect]="false"`, and pass the selected value and model reference to the component on change event, not click, and then close it manually.

So, try this:

add change event, pass selected value and the select model, and then do your checking, and close the select whenever some other value is selected, otherwise it will remain opened:

template:

```
<ng-select #ngSelectTa  (change)="reasonForAdding2($event, ngSelectTa)"  [closeOnSelect]="false"
```

component:

```
reasonForAdding2(otherReason:any, select:any) {
    
    console.log('otherReason', otherReason);

    if(otherReason !== 'Others - please specify your reason.') {
        select.close();
    } else {
        this.inputOtherReason = true;
    }
}
```

**edit**

to add input as an option, move it to the `ng-footer-tmp`, and then you can add else clause to set `this.inputOtherReason = true;`:

```
  <ng-template ng-footer-tmp>
                  <input *ngIf='inputOtherReason' [id]="s.site_nm" type="text" class="form-control inputsearch"
                    #inputSearch placeholder="Enter Reason For Adding" (keyup)="reasonForAddingOther(s,$event)"
                    [ngClass]="errorCheck(s)" />
</ng-template>
```

Comment: is there any way I can insert that input field with If condition inside ng-select as an option in the end ?